# How do I create a table using Pugjs or Jade

Tags: node.js, html-table, pug

I want to render this json file into the table using Pug but it doesn't happen as I want. I want the data in two languages and app_adi but only the latest data is coming. How can I display both?

JSON file

```
{
   "accounts":{
         "user":{
            "_id":"5a500vlflg0aslf011ld0a25a5",
            "username":"john",
            "id":"59d25992988fsaj19fe31d7",
            "name":"Test",
            "customer":" John Carew",
         },
         "application":[
            {
               "app_id":"5af56pi314-y1i96kdnqs871nih35",
               "language":"es"
            },
            {
               "app_id":"5af56pi314-blvinpgn4c95ywyt8j",
               "language":"en"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Code

```
 body
  main
    .container              
     table.table
        tr
          th username
          th customer
          th language
          th app_id
      tbody
        each users in accounts
          tr
            td #{users.user.name}
            td #{users.user.email}
            each app in application
                td #{app.language}
                td #{app.app_id}
```

I want to build this table:

```
username customer    language  app_di
john     John Carew   es        5af56pi314-y1i96kdnqs871nih35
                      en        5af56pi314-blvinpgn4c95ywyt8j
```

But when I run the above code I just get the last one, only language "en"?

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have it working, can you provide it in a working codepen? e.g., https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVLodd

Comment: codepen is not working on, but it works on the computer. As I said before, Why is it getting the latest data in the application?

Comment: We can't help with that as you have provided none of your server code.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has to do with where you're starting your `each` loop, but there are also some structural issues with your JSON.

I am assuming that you're passing the object into your route like this:

```
var data = { "accounts": ... }
res.render('templatename', data);
```

Which means that the accounts object will be at the root of your pug template when it is rendered.

When you create a loop on accounts (an object, not an array) pug will iterate over every property in that object, so your first each (`each users in accounts`) will give you these two values in the `users` variable:

1. user
2. application

I don't think that's what you want.  If you converted the `accounts.user` segment into an array you could successfully loop through a set of users like this:

```
each user in accounts.users
```

As for the second, you will need to reference the application as follows:

```
each application in accounts.application
```

---

Alternatively, you might be passing the data into the render function like this:

```
var data = { "accounts": ... }
res.render('templatename', data.accounts);
```

If you do it this way then you will loop through the users like this:

```
each user in users
```

The application loop will be this:

```
each application in applications
```

---

Please take a quick look at the [pug iteration docs](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) for more reference.

Comment: Sorry. But I didn't understand what you said.Where should I edit the code?

Comment: This all goes into your pug template, the one that starts with "body main"

Comment: The code is working, you just got the error somewhere? The solution to this should not be so complicated

Comment: Why do you say the code is working?  What error are you referring to?  This is not a complicated thing, and you do need to understand the basics of iteration to fix the issue in your question.